# Retry Login if Error Occurs

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have some tests that occasionally fail due to what we believe is some network drops, and so I changed my login method to retry the login after an error is displayed. I would like it to output to the console the number of times it had to retry as well. Is this the best way to go about this?

```
    login(email: string, password: string) {
        let count = 0
        if (!this.errorDisplayed()) {
            this.setEmail(email)
            this.setPassword(password)
            return this.clickSignIn()
        } while (this.errorDisplayed() && count < 5) {
            browser.refresh()
            count ++
        }
        console.log(`The login had errors this many ${count} times`)
    }
```

I have also tried the following:

```
    login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.setEmail(email)
    this.setPassword(password)
    this.clickSignIn()
    let count = 0
    this.errorDisplayed().then(result => {
        if (!result) {
            console.log(`No error was displayed`)
        } while (result && count < 5) {
            browser.refresh()
            count ++
        }
    })
    console.log(`The login had errors this many ${count} times`)
}
```

Comment: with what error tests occasionally fail?

Comment: So occasionally when the login goes to run there will be an error displayed and the login doesn't complete. So I need it to try to login, check for the error, and if it appears, refresh the browser and try again up to 5 times.

Comment: again, what exactly error appears? Protractor can not click on some button or server errror on whatever?

Comment: It is a 500 error when it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
    login(email: string, password: string) {
    let count = 0
    let maxTries = 5
    while(count <= maxTries) {
        try {
            this.setEmail(email)
            this.setPassword(password)
            return this.clickSignIn()
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Could not login because of: ${e.message}`)
            browser.refresh()
            if (++count === maxTries) {
                throw new Error('Failed to login after 5 tries')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is a solution? Probably, you have an issue in a server side. Currently, you just hide an issue with `while` function. I understand that tests should run. But, please, arise this issue with some guys, because as for me it is clearly an issue.

Comment: It is an issue, and I have brought it up. The dev manager is convinced it is only happening for me and not any of our customers.